# How to wire ground when using an arduino with transistors and an external power supply?

Tags: arduino, led, transistors, resistors, step-down

I am currently working on an arduino project for school, however some of my LEDs dont turn on, and i don't know why. Right now i am using the first diagram, where i merged all - poles (ground), and only the LEDs "rood"and "green" turn on when all pins get powered.
[image]
Will this problem be fixed if i wire it up like it is wired in the second diagram? where will the current from the arduino digital pins go to then, since there is no way for that current to go back into the arduino, or is this not a problem and does the loop only have to be closed for the battery? (dont look at the difference in resistors, that was just a mistake on my part by not adding them in the seond diagram too.)
[image]
Thanks,
Jasper

Comment: Without a current limiting resistor for leds 1 to 3 they could easily be destroyed - link to a data sheet is important. No, the 2nd picture won't work.

Comment: But the LEDs in the first picture wont turn on at all, they are not destroyed

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably with the way you use the transistors. In your schematic you drew Bipolar NPN transistors. Those switch based on the base-emitter-voltage, where the base has to be more positive then the emitter. In your current setup the base is whatever the output pin is set to, but the emitter is floating because it is not connected to any voltage. This is because you trying to use an NPN transistor on the positive side of the LED, but you´re supposed to use them on the negative side like in this schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9eRdT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here you can see that the base is whatever the output pin is (as long as there is no current going through R2) and the emitter is always grounded. Therefore a high output on the pin causes a positive base-emitter-voltage. Also note the resistors: R3 is the current limiting resistor for the LED to make sure it wont be destroyed because without it you´re basically shorting 3.5V to ground when the transistor is conducting. R1 is a pull-down resistor for the base of the transistor to make sure the base is never floating. R2 is a current limiting resistor to make sure you dont draw too much current from the output pin into the base of the resistor as this might damage the microcontroller.

Comment: What value is used for R1 and is this safe if your switching higher voltages than the microcontroller is using?